# MIDI Communication using React Native and Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, midi

I’m designing a mobile music program that needs to communicate with MIDI devices, bidirectionally. It needs to run on iOS and Android. If possible, also on Windows, macOS and GNU/Linux, but those three are of less priority. Now I am considering my options for frameworks.

I’ve looked in to React Native with Expo. It seems very straight forward for implementing the user interface. The only thing I am worried about is the lack of support for MIDI. At least I cannot find any information about this.

Is there any way to add support for MIDI devices to React Native with Expo, or do I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-orchestra or https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi-sounds-react or using google there are more ready solutions? You might also want to check this: https://github.com/HridayK97/Android-Piano

Comment: Thanks, but none of the two first mentioned seems to support MIDI communication. The last one might do, but is exclusive to Android.

Comment: As you may know in react-native when some lib introduces new functionality like a driver to midi it's actually written for all platforms in native technology not in JS so behind component like <MidiDevice> should be native solution. You have to find solutions for all desired platforms. I personally don't know cross-platform react-native lib allowing connection to midi devices. Also note web target might be impossible.

Comment: For now I care most for iOS and Android. Web target should be possible to support via Web MIDI API.

Comment: good to know, I didn't know there is such API. EDIT: But as I see browser support is poor.

Comment: Yes, currently. It’s part of HTML5 so more extensive support is hopefully coming. For now only Chrome on desktops and Android is supported.

Comment: For iOS specifically, this project exists which makes WebMIDI work in a native iOS WebView: https://github.com/mizuhiki/WebMIDIAPIShimForiOS

It hasn't been updated in years, but I just compiled and tested it last night and it works without any issues